# Is there a way for an HTTP/1.1 only client to communicate with a server that seemingly defaults to HTTP/2 WITHOUT updating the client?

Tags: http2, http-1.1

I am trying to connect to a server that defaults to HTTP/2 with Apach Http-Components 3.4, which is not HTTP/2 compatible.  I see [here](https://http2-explained.haxx.se/content/en/part5.html#51-http2-for-existing-uri-schemes) that a client can request HTTP/2 from the server via the `Upgrade` header.  Is there a way to request HTTP/1.1 from the server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it should be the default. A server should only HTTP/2 to a client if it was previously negotiated.

Either:

- through an upgrade from HTTP/1 through the HTTP `Upgrade` header
- through protocol negotiation (ALPN) during the TLS handshake

It is theoretically possible to force HTTP/2 on both sides without negotation. This is called HTTP/2 with prior-knowledge. However that mode shouldn't be used on public servers, since it exactly causes the problems that you are having.

I would try to speak to the developers/maintainers of the server if the HTTP/2 only behavior is intended.